# How can I get plugins for emesene 2?

Tags: software-recommendation, msn, emesene

Emesene 2 is cool, but it lacks the additional plugins present in the previous version (see screenshot below; the plugins tab is empty in emesene 2). 
So where can I find plugins to download?

[image: Emesene 2: Plugins tab is empty]

[image: Emesene 1]

Is there a way to copy the plugins from emesene 1 to emesene 2?
If not , any suggestion for another client for MSN has all the plugins needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emesene 2 was only recently (rushed to release) released. For this reason a lot of the old plugins have yet to be ported. You could download some from GIT (see the emesene github page), but they will not be as useful.

Comment: Plugins also empty in Github :
https://github.com/emesene/emesene/tree/master/emesene/plugins

Comment: @binarylie: true, and they haven't clearly defined what is the difference between extensions and plugins.

Comment: Well , I guess I should wait for an update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @binarylife: I'm waiting too :)